# Simple Date Difference Code

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I have been trying to get this code executed. I am a beginner and am practising HTML/Javascript out with simple examples. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript">
    function dateDiff()
    {
      var f1, f2, d1, d2, one_day, diff;
      f1=document.getElementById("f1");
      f2=document.getElementById("f2");
      d1=new Date(f1);
      d2=new Date(f2);
      one_day=1000*60*60*24;
      diff=Math.ceil((d1.value()-d2.value())/(one_day));
      alert
      {
        ("The difference is" +diff.value()+ "days");
      }
   }
   </script>
   <form>
     <input type=date name=f1 id=f1>
     <input type=date name=f2 id=f2>
     <input type=button name=f3 value="Get Difference" onclick="dateDiff">
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get? What value are you passing to `new Date()`? Leaving parsing of date strings to the Date constructor is notoriously error prone.

Comment: Well @RobG , I'm trying to take the inputs from the form and passing it to new Date(). And, I'm not getting any errors at all. I'm just using notepad and chrome, you see.

Comment: I think it's a scope issue. You're calling `alert()` on an element, but it needs to be called at the scope of window. See: http://javascript.info/tutorial/binding

Answer (score 1):

Other than the probably errors with Date parsing strings, you have:

```
alert
{
("The difference is" +diff.value()+ "days");
}
```

*alert* is a method, so there should not be a block between the name and parameter list, and the value of *diff* is a number that doesn't have a *value* method, try:

```
alert("The difference is" + diff + "days");
```

You may have been told that primitives are coerced to objects when evaluating expressions if required, so you can do:

```
var a = 4;
alert( a.valueOf() );  // 4
```

In order to display the value of *a*, *alert* will call *toString* which effectively the same as calling *valueOf* and coverting it to a string:

```
alert( a.toString() );  // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/Javascript">
        function dateDiff()
        {
            var f1, f2, d1, d2, one_day, diff;
            f1=document.getElementById("f1").value; // .value to get value of input text.
            f2=document.getElementById("f2").value; // .value to get value of input text.

            d1=new Date(f1);
            d2=new Date(f2);
            one_day=1000*60*60*24;
            diff=Math.ceil((d1-d2)/(one_day)); // d1-d2 but not d1.value()-d2.value()
            alert("The difference is" +diff+ "days"); // alert the difference of d1 and d2 by diff but not diff.value().
        }
        </script>
        <form>
            <input type=date name=f1 id=f1>
            <input type=date name=f2 id=f2>
            <input type=button name=f3 value="Get Difference" onclick="dateDiff()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```